# Slow running query, Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a very slow query (30+ minutes or more) that I think can be sped up with more efficient coding. Below is the code and the query plan that results. So I am looking for answers to speed up with query that is performing several joins on large tables.

```
drop table if exists totalshad;
create temporary table totalshad as
select pricedate, hour, sum(cast(price as numeric)) as totalprice from 
pjm.rtcons
where
rtcons.pricedate >= '2017-12-01'
--  and
--  rtcons.pricedate <= '2018-01-23'
group by pricedate, hour
order by pricedate, hour;
-----------------------------
drop table if exists percshad;
create temporary table percshad as
select totalshad.pricedate, totalshad.hour, facility, round(sum(cast(price 
as numeric)),2) as cons_shad, round(sum(cast(totalprice as numeric)),2) as 
total_shad, round(cast(price/totalprice as numeric),4) as per_shad from 
totalshad
join pjm.rtcons on
rtcons.pricedate = totalshad.pricedate
and
rtcons.hour = totalshad.hour
and
facility = 'ETOWANDA-NMESHOPP ETL 1057  A  115 KV'
where totalprice <> 0 and totalshad.pricedate > '2017-12-01'
group by totalshad.pricedate, totalshad.hour, facility, 
(price/totalprice)
order by per_shad desc
limit 5;

EXPLAIN select facility, percshad.pricedate, percshad.hour, per_shad, 
minmcc.rtmcc, minnode.nodename, maxmcc.rtmcc, maxnode.nodename from percshad
join pjm.prices minmcc on
minmcc.pricedate = percshad.pricedate
and
minmcc.hour = percshad.hour
and
minmcc.rtmcc = (select min(rtmcc) from pjm.prices where pricedate = 
percshad.pricedate and hour = percshad.hour)
join pjm.nodes minnode on
minnode.node_id = minmcc.node_id
join pjm.prices maxmcc on
maxmcc.pricedate = percshad.pricedate
and
maxmcc.hour = percshad.hour
and
maxmcc.rtmcc = (select max(rtmcc) from pjm.prices where pricedate = 
percshad.pricedate and hour = percshad.hour)
join pjm.nodes maxnode on
maxnode.node_id = maxmcc.node_id
order by per_shad desc
limit 5
```

And here is the EXPLAIN output:

[image: EXPLAIN OUTPUT]

UPDATE: I have now simplified my code down to the following. But as can be seen from the EXPLAIN, it stills takes forever to find the node_id in the last select statement

```
 drop table if exists totalshad;
create temporary table totalshad as
select pricedate, hour, sum(cast(price as numeric)) as totalprice from 
pjm.rtcons
where
rtcons.pricedate >= '2017-12-01'
--  and
--  rtcons.pricedate <= '2018-01-23'
group by pricedate, hour
order by pricedate, hour;
-----------------------------
drop table if exists percshad;
create temporary table percshad as
select totalshad.pricedate, totalshad.hour, facility, round(sum(cast(price 
as numeric)),2) as cons_shad, round(sum(cast(totalprice as numeric)),2) as 
total_shad,
round(cast(price/totalprice as numeric),4) as per_shad from totalshad
join pjm.rtcons on
rtcons.pricedate = totalshad.pricedate
and
rtcons.hour = totalshad.hour
and
facility = 'ETOWANDA-NMESHOPP ETL 1057  A  115 KV'
where totalprice <> 0 and totalshad.pricedate > '2017-12-01'
group by totalshad.pricedate, totalshad.hour, facility, (price/totalprice)
order by per_shad desc
limit 5;

drop table if exists mincong;
create temporary table mincong as
select pricedate, hour, min(rtmcc) as rtmcc
from pjm.prices JOIN percshad USING (pricedate, hour)
group by pricedate, hour;

EXPLAIN select distinct on (pricedate, hour) prices.node_id from mincong 
JOIN pjm.prices USING (pricedate, hour, rtmcc)
group by pricedate, hour, node_id
```

[image: EXPLAIN 2]

Comment: The first thing that I would try is putting indexes on `percshad`.  (Yes, you can do that with temporary tables.)

Comment: You might not be gaining speed by using temp tables.

Comment: tell us  what are the columns are indexed in your query

Comment: For future questions: please do not show us the plan as an image (that doesn't even show the full plan). Use [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). And the output of **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** is usually much more helpful. You can also upload the plan to  http://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Using PgAdmin4, when I hit F7 for EXPLAIN I just get: syntax error at or near "drop". Additionally, I cannot copy and paste the explain output. Hence my need to use the screenshot. If there's another way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the subselects in the join condition; they have to be executed for every row joined.

If you cannot get rid of them, try to create an index that will support the subselects as good as possible:

```
CREATE INDEX ON pjm.prices(pricedate, hour, rtmcc);
```

Comment: Would it help to join with the subselect instead of using it in the joind condition?

Comment: Joining with a subselect is usually much better than having one in a join condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried incorporating your suggestions. It still runs slow. See my updated question. Also, I cannot INDEX the pjm.prices as I am not the owner.

Comment: Well, you can get the DBA to create an index. But for a hash join you don't need it. You should `ANALYZE` the temporary tables before using them. Can you provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output?